# remote connecting to laptop

Tags: vnc

I have connected my raspberry pi model 3 B to my laptop remotely using SSH. I am able to connect to the terminal, but when im trying to view using VNC viewer all I am getting is a gray screen.

Comment: I don't believe this is a problem specific to the Raspberry Pi, and you may find more information by googling "vnc viewer gray screen"

Comment: Hello. Can you add to your question the OS you've installed to your SD card and which desktop manager you're using?

Comment: Hey, the OS i have installed is buster lite. After enabling the GUI settings it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

> If a grey screen is encountered change /root/.vnc/xstartup contents to
>   this: *[Source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=216725#p1334085)*

```
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
startxfce4 &

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
```